# JSON acentos API Restful

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, slimframework

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou criando um API para estudo, porém to com alguns problemas com acentos.

Quando faço uma pesquisa, tenho uma resposta de não encontrado.

Segue a baixo um teste.

[image: Esse primeiro teste ele funciona corretamente, mas a consulta não chega até os acentos]

[image: Esse segundo teste ele não funciona, faço a pesquisa com os acentos]

[image: Esse terceiro teste ele também não funciona, faço a pesquisa com a url codificada]

Teria alguma solução para que eu resolva essa situação?

P.S: Uso Slim Framework

Answer (score 0):

Ao receber os dados no PHP utilize um encode para transferir os dados para a varíavel:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input',true));
$texto= utf8_encode($json->{"texto"});
```

e para devolver os dados:

```
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Tenha certeza que o JSON enviado está em UTF-8